# Finland - SIM Card provider with data plans

Tags: internet, data-plans, finland, mobile-operators

I will be visiting Finland for 1 month near the end of this month, for a business trip. I would like to know how easy it is to get a SIM card with a data plan right after I land at the Helsinki Airport; and perhaps some recommendations on which providers have the best coverage. Price is not really a concern, I just need to ensure that the data access is very stable. I would be happy to hear your thoughts.

I went through a few mobile provider websites by googling it, but unfortunately I cannot read Finnish.

Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of questions about getting SIM cards in Europe. Assuming you have a unlocked GSM phone. You just walk into a phone shop or convince store, hand them somewhere between 8 and 10 euros for a SIM and credit basically anywhere in Europe and that's it. You don't need a contract or anything complicated. If you're spending most of your time in urban areas coverage doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three major networks in Finland Elisa, DNA and Telia. All of them have a really good coverage in the whole country and unless you're going to a specific place in the countryside I wouldn't worry too much about the coverage. Coverage maps for all the operators are here [Elisa](https://elisa.fi/kuuluvuus/), [DNA](https://kartat.dna.fi/Peittokartta/) and [Sonera](https://www.telia.fi/asiakastuki/verkko/verkko/verkkokartta). The best and probably only place at the airport to buy a SIM-card is R-kioski for which you can see details here https://www.r-kioski.fi/tuotteet/prepaid-liittymat. (Should be google translatable)